# How do we use the runway condition assessment matrix?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, takeoff, runways, runway-contamination

Starting on October 1st, 2016 the FAA is moving away from providing Mu values for runway friction reports to a new format showing contamination type and depth for each third of the runway.  Along with the report is a code X/X/X showing runway condition codes for each third of the runway.

**How do we, as pilots, use the field condition NOTAMs in calculating takeoff and landing performance?**

[image: FAA RCAM matrix]

Comment: What was wrong with Mu values?

Comment: @acpilot - [Snoopy](http://cdn.quotesgram.com/small/17/16/1360572701-P1130255.jpg), while already [tri-lingual](http://cdn.quotesgram.com/small/1/45/212640267-f9595a928ccd1669fdbc8d3b41b70cc5.jpg), had to learn a fourth language to speak Mu.

Comment: I knew it must have been a good reason!

Answer (score 3):

From the [*FAA Improves Runway Conditions Reporting*](https://www.faa.gov/news/updates/?newsId=85985) article:

> The pilot or dispatcher would then consult the **aircraft manufacturer data** to determine what kind of stopping performance to expect from the specific airplane they are operating.

The important bit:

> The FAA is advising operators to **develop procedures** for pilots and dispatchers that address the changes to runway condition reporting procedures.

Here are the corresponding braking coefficients:

[image]

From: [Takeoff Performance Data for Operations on Contaminated Runways](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_25-31.pdf), aimed at manufacturers.

Comment: In other words, there is no answer yet...

Comment: @FreeMan updated answer